# Only show X rows from DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid, rss, twitter

I want to post my 5 recent twitters on my website. I've build a datagrid with XMLTextReader in C# which reads the feed but the problem I face is that it shows ALL the feeds and I can't find a way to only show 5. Any idea's?

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://some.rss/feed.rss");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
        dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dg.AllowPaging = false;
        dg.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer directly your question:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"
              PageSize="5" AllowPaging="true">
   <PagerSettings Visible="false" />
</asp:GridView>
```

But I'm just wondering, why not trying to use a C# wrapper for Twitter API?

like:

http://devblog.yedda.com/index.php/2007/05/16/twitter-c-library/

or follow the fantastic post of Petar in

http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/petar/Blog/archive/2008/06/23/twitter-wcf-client.aspx

**P.S.** add twitter to your tags!

Answer (score 1):

How about the simple solution of manually deleting all the rows from the DataTable except the first 5?

Comment: Well, for example, like this:

            while ( dTbl.Rows.Count > 5 ) dTbl.Rows.RemoveAt(dTbl.Rows.Count-1);

Answer (score 1):

Better still, the Twitter API allows you to specify a "since ID" value.  That way you can request only updates since the latest one you have.